# NHibernate: How to add more than one assembly?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, orm

I am using NHibernate 4 and I have a simple SQL Server database that contains some tables: `Orders`, `Products`, etc ...

[NHibernate mapping classes and hbm files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhRYm.png)

And I have the following helper class:

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Orders).Assembly);
                /*configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Products).Assembly);*/

                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

The class works good when it just contains

```
configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Orders).Assembly);
```

The problem is when I call `AddAssembly` method to add a second table mapping class like `Products`.

I get an error:

> Could not compile the mapping document: StockManager.DBMapping.Orders.hbm.xml

My question is: how to call `AddAssembly` method for another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [FluentNhibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) instead of xml mapping.

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* database config */)
  .Mappings(m =>
    m.AutoMappings
      .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Products>())
      .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Orders>())
   )
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

and also you may use auto mapping generic base classes. An example of this is using a single generic argument to dictate the Id type.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>  
{  
  public T Id { get; private set; }  
}

public class Product : BaseEntitiy<int> 
{
  //do stuff
}
```

When using this kind of base-class, you just need to ignore it like any other base type.

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Entity>()
  .IgnoreBase(typeof(BaseEntity<>));
```